# Múltiplas transações com FireDAC?

Tags: delphi, transações, firedac

Gostaria de trabalhar com múltiplas transações simultâneas no *FireDAC*, tomando decisões (*rollbacks* e *commits*) diferentes para cada uma. É possível? 
Atualmente, trabalho da seguinte forma:

```
try
  obj_TFDConnection.StartTransaction();
  ...
  obj_TFDConnection.Commit();
except
  obj_TFDConnection.Rollback();
end;
```

Porém, assim só consigo gerenciar uma transação de cada vez.

Comment: Documentação oficial com a soluação: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Managing_Transactions_(FireDAC)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo a transação do FireDAC é conceitualmente diferente da transação do DBX. Acontece que ambos trabalham com multi transações; O que quero dizer que na pratica você pode abrir uma transação, executar algum tipo de alteração no banco, abrir outra transação efetuar novas mudanças e assim por diante. A questão central é que temos uma grande diferença entre o FireDAC e o DBX na maneira como é visto isso. Então implica diretamente em como vc trabalhar. Vejamos:

Tomamos como exemplo duas tabelas, e teremos que fazer uma ação, que consiste em fazer um insert em cada tabela, se ambos forem executados sem problemas é commit e retornamos "OK" para a função principal.

No DBX iremo perceber que a segunda transação não tem relacionado com a primeira. Sou seja se der commit na primeira e rollback na segunda vai ser ao final teremos somente uma inserção;

Já no FireDAC a mesma situação. Se tivermos commit na primeira e rollback na segunda, ambas as transações sofrerão rollback; É como se a primeira manda em tudo.

Isso é uma enorme diferença se vc estiver pensando em migrar;

Answer (score -1):

Quando venderam o PODER do FireDAC vendo a imagem de conseguir reconectar ao banco de dados (sem perder os dados) foi um milagre...
Mas não contaram os Pós que iriamos enfrentar para quem vem do DBX...
Foi barra, mas consegue resolver assim;

**Transaction1 := TFDTransaction.Create(nil);
Transaction1.Connection := TDtMdl(DtMdl).SQLCnctnBancoDados;
Transaction1.Options.AutoCommit := False;
Transaction1.Options.DisconnectAction := xdRollback;**

**Transaction2 := TFDTransaction.Create(nil);
Transaction2.Connection := TDtMdl(DtMdl).SQLCnctnBancoDados;
Transaction2.Options.AutoCommit := False;
Transaction2.Options.DisconnectAction := xdRollback;**

SQL1 := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
SQL1.Connection := TDtMdl(DtMdl).SQLCnctnBancoDados;
SQL1.Connection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
SQL1.Transaction := **Transaction1;**

SQL2 := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
SQL2.Connection := TDtMdl(DtMdl).SQLCnctnBancoDados;
SQL2.Connection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
SQL2.Transaction := **Transaction2;**

try
if Transaction1.Active = False then
Transaction1.StartTransaction;

if Transaction2.Active = False then
Transaction2.StartTransaction;

Transaction1.commit;
Transaction2.commit;
except
Transaction1.rollback;
Transaction2.rollback;
end;

obs.
Todos os SQL rodados no SQL1, será tratado na transaction1
Todos os SQL rodados no SQL2, será tratado na teansaction2

Espero ter ajudado;
[]´s